# How to make the search function on a website

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I was just wondering how do I make my website preview some info after the user searches for something stored in the database.

Comment: Wlecome on SO, before asking please read this [mcve]

Comment: Can you describe the problem further? The question is too casual and generic.

Comment: You can use Ajax : when user search something you search what user is typing in your database and display what you get in "real time"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Basic approach for previewing user names as you type in a search bar. For this to work, you will need to use AJAX to query the server and also display the result as a preview for the user to click on if they want, without having to refresh the page.

- User types 'Joe' into the search bar
- The onChange() even is fired and you query your server with that the user has written "Joe". Keep in mind this query is via AJAX, so as not to force the page to reload.
- Server side, you do a MySQL lookup of the table users, where the name is something like "Joe". `SELECT NAME FROM USERS WHERE NAME LIKE '%what_you_sent_on_AJAX_request%' LIMIT 10;`
- The browser receives the response from the AJAX request and displays a nice dropdown with the output of the server. When the user actually click son this "previews" it is in that moment that you would actually reload to the page or take the user to a new page based on what they have clicked on.

That's a very basic approach for it.